# Oracle AWR reports : whether parse time include in DB CPU?

Tags: oracle

There is time model statistics in awr report, is the parse time include in DB CPU time or separate from ?
I've found my database exists a large parse time problem,and I would like to estimate the benefits that can be achieved by reducing the parse time.
thanks!

Comment: I believe parse time is included. Are you looking at hard or soft parses?

Comment: thanks BobC,but i know hard & soft parse time is already include in parse time,did any documentation mention about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Time Model Statistics**

DB Time represents total time in user calls

DB CPU represents CPU time of foreground processes

Total CPU Time represents foreground and background processes

Statistics including the word "background" measure background process time, therefore do not contribute to the DB time statistic

Ordered by % of DB time in descending order, followed by Statistic Name
[image]

we have identify that DB cpu is taking more time .
We will CPU ORDERED by CPU Time. There will how queries are taking time along with Execution time .Select query and check tunning advisor and find recommendation on same.

[image]

I hope i have clear your answer.